# Scraping Webpage using Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im using selenium to access my school grades and after that i want to be able to scrape my grades from the site but i dont know how

Here is my login code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS("C:\Python27\phantomjs-1.9.0-windows\phantomjs.exe") 
driver.get("https://ps.rsd.edu/public/")

elem = driver.find_element_by_name("account")
elem.send_keys("Username")
elem2 = driver.find_element_by_name("pw")
elem2.send_keys("Password")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

driver.quit()

print "done"
```

I think the easiest way is to use Beautifulsoup but im not sure

Comment: well i guess i could do that but id like to just get the grades off the site and can i do screenshots if the window isnt there because im running the driver with phantomjs

Comment: so i can use to selenium to get the info and return it because this is just a part of a larger program that takes my grades and makes it my desktop background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer this here as the other question is about how to parse the table using Beautifulsoup.

So given the table at http://gist.github.com/C-Dubb/5522909

```python
for cell in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".grid tr a[href$='fg=S2']"):
    print cell.text
    # if you want the number only, you need to strip the grades here
    # also need to check if S2 cell is empty or not
```